# R ffbase save.ffdf error ( NA were not saved, because not found )

Tags: r, export, data.table, ffbase

I have a large data.table (let's call it DT) in R which takes too long to save as csv (would be great to have a fast writer similar to fread). Therefore I am converting the data.table to a ffdf object:

> library(data.table)
>   library(ffbase)
>   ffiles <- as.ffdf(DT)

This works and I can see the object. Also when transforming ffiles to a data.frame, by doing

> DF <- as.data.frame (ffiles)

.. I see the flat files being opened and loaded. However, if I try to save the ffiles, by doing

> save.ffdf(ffiles,dir=path-to-folder, overwrite=TRUE)

I get the error: 
NA were not saved, because not found

What could cause this?

BTW: I have set fftempdir as options before.

PS: could someone create a "ff" or "ffbase" tag? Don't have enough reputation:-/

Comment: First, why don't you save the `data.table` using `saveRDS`?

Comment: Second, I can not reproduce the error. I am using the iris dataset. Could you give an reproducible example? Also, `save.ffdf` does not have an `overwrite` argument, so this should also give an error.

Comment: Jan.. thank you for looking into this. I don't have a reproducible example.. it should not happen, but sometimes I get this error and I don't know why... therefore I was wondering what generally could cause this and whether someone else had such an error

Comment: Also, please check again: save.ffdf does have an overwrite argument

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems like one error was based on the way I indicated the path-to-folder.
Using "C:\\Folder\\folder\\file" to set the directory  seems not to work properly?
However, using "C:/Folder/folder/file"  seems to do the job.

Nevertheless, I keep on having continuous issues with the ff-files on a network (e.g., they do not load after saving them).

SaveRDS and ReadRDS seem to do a great job for quickly saving and reading in large files (which are also compressed). So thanks for that Jan!